# Find all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $30^n \equiv 20 \pmod {38}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, divisibility, roots-of-unity

The full problem was to actually find all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $w^{{30}^n} = -w^{4^5+21}$, with $w$ being a primitive 38th root of unity.

I've proven that the right side of the equation equals 1, so now I'm left with proving that $30^{n}+208 \equiv 0 \pmod {38}$ which leads to $30^n \equiv 20 \pmod{38}$
And here I got stuck, I've got no clue how to continue. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: $30^3\equiv20\bmod38$

Comment: Thanks for answering! I did realize that 18 is a solution, so all multiples of 18 must be. But I tried using dcode.fr modular exponentiation calculator to see the answer and I get that n is congruent to 0 mod 3. Any idea why?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes, I realized that using an online calculator. But I don't understand how to get there. Thanks for the help!

Comment: $30^n\equiv20\bmod38$ means $11^n\equiv1\bmod19$.  It happens that $11^3=1331=19*70+1$

Comment: Shouldn't you be wanting to prove 19(mod 38), saying because as i simplified RHS with an arbitrary $w$, i received the 2$^{nd}$ roots of unity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write out the period

$30\equiv -8\pmod{38}$

$30^2\equiv 64\equiv-12\pmod{38}$

$30^3\equiv96\equiv20 \pmod{38}$

$30^4\equiv-160\equiv30\pmod{38}$

The period is short and you can see every $3k$ is a solution. Sometimes the dumb way is the best way.

Answer (score 1):

Since $30^n\equiv 20\pmod2$ for all $n>0$, we only need to consider $11^n\equiv30^n\equiv 20\equiv1\pmod{19}$. Since the order of $11\pmod{19}$ is $3$, this happens for all positive multiples of $3$.